# How to stop pipe if the HTML input element's value isn't changed with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm using RxJS with Angular 9. I try to add a keyup binding to my input and if the user typed a new value I want to start a HTTP request.

I have this code:

```js
fromEvent(this.inputBox.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    // wait 300 ms to start
    debounceTime(300),
    // if value is the same, ignore
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // start connection
    switchMap(term => this.autocompleteService.search({term: myterm}))
  ).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Now If I hit the left arrow key (the value isn't change) the `autocompleteService.search()` will run.

I read in the RxJS documentation the `disctinctUntilChanged()` will stop the pipe flow. But didn't.

I tried this code too, but not working:

```js
distinctUntilChanged((prevent: HTMLInputElement, current: HTMLInputElement) =>
  prevent.value === current.value),
```

How can I stop pipe continuing if the HTML input element's value isn't changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `distinctUntilChanged` only emits when the current value is different than the last as you know already.

However, please notice the word **value**.

You use `distinctUntilChanged`, but what exactly does this operator operates on?

`fromEvent` does listen to the **keyup** event and as expected it will emit the `KeyboardEvent` object.

This can be proved by adding the `tap` operator to your current implementation:

```
fromEvent(this.inputBox.nativeElement, 'keyup')
 .pipe(
  // wait 300 ms to start
  debounceTime(300),
  tap(e => console.log(e)),
  // if value is the same, ignore
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  // start connection
  switchMap(term => this.autocompleteService.search({term: myterm}))
).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
console.log(result);
});
```

So `distinctUntilChanged` won't do a deep object comparison.

Instead, extract the value with the `map` operator and then it should work as expected:

```
fromEvent(this.inputBox.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    map(val => val.target.value),
    distinctUntilChanged(), 
    switchMap(val => this.search(val))
  ).subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure with `fromEvent`, you get `term` right away? I would imagine you would get the `Event` (the key pressed, etc. etc.).

Try:

```
fromEvent(this.inputBox.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
  map(event => this.inputBox.nativeElement.value),
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev: string, curr: string) => prev === curr),
  switchMap(term => this.autocompleteService.search({term: myterm})),
).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The problem with this approach is that it needs to be emitted twice for it to do the comparison with previous value in `distinctUntilChanged` and if the first character typed was a left arrow, then it will be subscribed and send the request.

You may want to try the `filter` operator.

```
fromEvent(this.inputBox.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
  map(event => this.inputBox.nativeElement.value),
  filter(term => /* don't emit if the term has weird characters that you can decide on */),
  debounceTime(300),
  switchMap(term => this.autocompleteService.search({term: myterm})),
).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I don't even think the `distinctUntilChanged` is needed now since mapping it to `this.inputBox.nativeElement.value` will not absorb the arrow keys.